# how to automatically generate the dynamic waveform of any audio with javascript and canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, waveform

My question is that how to automatically generate the dynamic waveform of any audio with javascript and canvas?
I'm working on a website similar to soundcloud and I'm stuck at a point where I've to embed a script for generating waveform automatically when I or user upload song on website. is there any script I can use similar to soundcloud.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the wavesurfer.js library they get examples you can dwonload and play with and this library is well  documented and maintained

https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js

Comment: Yeah i have seen there but i want just like sound cloud waveform

Comment: you mean bar instead of plain wave , they got it

Comment: they even have someone that build sound cloud clone posting about it , dig in to the pull request you'll see it